# creating an interactive map in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, procedural-generation

I am trying to create a fictional map which I can zoom in and out to resize and view finer details and that also includes clickable regions like markers.
Essentially I am trying to create something like the following:

https://www.ign.com/maps/gta-5/los-santos-blaine-county

https://www.worldanvil.com/w/WorldAnvilCodex/map/ae7a3c29-5398-4cdb-8cc4-4e9f2e3b4275

EDIT: the attached image is an example of a map. What I am planning on doing is making this map interactive where a user of a website can zoom, pan and click on links/pins etc. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7JZ1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use pure js if you are completely new and try the google maps api. It has extensive documentation and if you are stuck Stackoverflow has a lot of answers on various levels of questions.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a custom image using the google map API?

Comment: what do you mean by a custom image? Adding icons on a map? If that is the case yes you can.